# Saving the file in folder mentioned by user HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a code in which I want certain tweaks to be done.
The "save text to file" downloads the text file in the download folder. I want it to prompt me for the path. It should ask me where to save the file and the download part should happen at the back end and should not be visible.

Here is the code for reference

```
<html>
<body>

<table>
    <tr><td>Text to Save:</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <textarea id="inputTextToSave" cols="80" rows="25"></textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Filename to Save As:</td>
        <td><input id="inputFileNameToSaveAs"></input></td>
        <td><button onclick="saveTextAsFile()">Save Text to File</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Select a File to Load:</td>
        <td><input type="file" id="fileToLoad"></td>
        <td><button onclick="loadFileAsText()">Load Selected File</button><td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">

function saveTextAsFile()
{
    var textToSave = document.getElementById("inputTextToSave").value;
    var textToSaveAsBlob = new Blob([textToSave], {type:"text/plain"});
    var textToSaveAsURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(textToSaveAsBlob);
    var fileNameToSaveAs = document.getElementById("inputFileNameToSaveAs").value;

    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
    downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
    downloadLink.href = textToSaveAsURL;
    downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
    downloadLink.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

    downloadLink.click();
}

function destroyClickedElement(event)
{
    document.body.removeChild(event.target);
}

function loadFileAsText()
{
    var fileToLoad = document.getElementById("fileToLoad").files[0];

    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) 
    {
        var textFromFileLoaded = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
        document.getElementById("inputTextToSave").value = textFromFileLoaded;
    };
    fileReader.readAsText(fileToLoad, "UTF-8");
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "the download part should happen at the back end" — You're working in client side JavaScript, there is no back end.

Comment: When I say back end I mean that file being  downloaded should not be visible in the frame/screen

Comment: The question that you are referring to is different from what i have asked.

Comment: For Chrome and other browsers, the default is to save to the downloads folder.  However, the end user can change this option by telling the browser to ask where to save a file.  The webpage itself cannot do this, since it would be a potential security risk.  So a web developer could not make a page to ask where to save, but the client-side user can tell the browser to always ask.

Comment: Can we somehow write the data from the text box to a text file (in any location) so that it can be read afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You can not download a file using JavaScript to a different location because this poses a security risk to the users computer. The only thing that you could do would be to download the text file into the users download folder. However, if you really need to download the file to a different directory you may be able to do it with a browser extension. There is also no way to make sure the user can not see the file downloading. If you really want the user to not see the file downloading you may be able to use a drive by download but those bugs usually get patched by bar owners very quickly.

Comment: Can you please tell me the name of the extension that you are talking about

Comment: I am talking about building your own extension

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong,
so java script cannot save the file in a particular folder but it has read permission and can read from the browser.

Comment: JavaScript does not have read permissions for files on computers

Comment: If you run the above code, it is able to load a file, read it and display it in the text box.

Comment: @RajSharma sorry about that. I did not realize JavaScript had that many permissions.

Comment: Thats fine, but are you sure we cannot download a file to a different location?

Comment: @RajSharma you would be able to do it just not without user input. The user would have to change the download folder.